# Laravel table referencing itself through pivot

Tags: php, laravel

I have one table called roles:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('image')->default("noImage.png");
        $table->timestamps();
      });
```

and another table roles_roles

```
Schema::create('roles_roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer("role_id")->unsigned();
        $table->integer("role_inherit_from_id")->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'd like one role to reference many other roles (to say one role can inherit from multiple others)
`public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany(Role::class, "roles_roles", "role_inherit_from_id");`

but get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles.roles_roles' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `roles`.`roles_roles` is null and `roles`.`roles_roles` is not null limit 1)
}`
```

Does anyone know how to implement a table that can reference itself, or a way to get around this?

Comment: Mabe you need `belongsToMany`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `belongsToMany` instead?

```
   $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'roles_roles', 'role_id', 'role_inherit_from_id');
```

Also, you have wrong syntax `hasMany`

```
$this->hasMany(Model::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Documentatios: [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).